# Using Tensorflow to make a prediction missing argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, predict, tf.keras

I am trying to load my trained model to make a prediction but I am getting an error (see below) when I call `model.predict()`. The model was trained on 2 GPUs using `MirroredStrategy()`. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

smooth = 1
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

model = load_model('test_model', compile = False, custom_objects = {'dice_coef_loss': dice_coef_loss, 'dice_coef': dice_coef})

prediction = model.predict(norm_images, verbose = 1)
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'loss'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must predict from "your model", not from the "class" model.

```
model.predict(norm_images, verbose=1)
```

Hint: since you're not compiling, you don't need the `custom_objects`, because they're all related to the loss.

Comment: When I make that change I get the error `AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'loss'`

Comment: That doesn't make sense. This error must be coming from code that you didn't write in the question. But you need `compile=True` for anything related to training (loss, optimizer and metrics).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I called model.summary() on my model that was trained with a single gpu and my multigpu trained model. My multigpu model shows nothing was saved. Pretty sure that is the problem.